# Как нормально вывести keys() и values() из json?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Хочу достать из json ключи и значения по отдельности. Вот код:

```py
result = data_json['result']
for i in result:
    a = t.keys()
    b = t.values()
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

Получается вывод такой:

```py
dict_keys(['a','b','c','d'])
dict_values(['1','2','3','4'])
```

Как вывести голые ключи, без скобок, кавычек и dict_keys(values)?

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,3,4
```

Связанный вопрос - как потом (или сразу) обрамить кавычками нужные ключи и значения? Что-то типа этого:

```
a,'b',c,'d'
1,2,'3',d
```

Comment: `>> Связанный вопрос - как потом (или сразу) обрамить кавычками нужные кейсы и вэлюесы? Что-то типа этого:` а зачем это?

Comment: @gil9red, для формирования запроса в бд

Comment: Не советую, это не удобно и это путь к sql-инъекциям. Передавайте параметры как binding. Т.е. в строке sql вместо параметров будут символы `?`, а параметры будут помещены рядом. Драйвер sql сам разместит. Пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/get_actual_news_from_rss_ya/webserver/common.py#L80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
result = data_json['result']
for t in result:
    a = t.keys()
    b = t.values()
    print(','.join(a))
    print(','.join(b))
```

Если у вас ключи и значения не обязательно строки, тогда нужно сделать их строками, иначе `join` не сработает:

```
    print(','.join(map(str, a)))
    print(','.join(map(str, b)))
```

Answer (score 1):

А я делаю обычно так:

```
result = data_json['result']
for i in result:
    a = list(t.keys())
    b = list(t.values())
    print(a)
    print(b)
```